# Android Studio Mac OSX: JSON File Size exceeds configured limit (2560000). Code insight features not Available

Tags: json, macos, android-studio

I'm working on an android app where I parse a 4.8 mb JSON file into an sqlite database which I then access to display data in list view. The listview due to the error/flag mentioned in question title I think is preventing all the items from showing in list view. Is there a way to configure the max file size?

Answer (score 4):

Code insights for json file is not necessary. Anyway, follow these steps:

Open the IntelliJ IDEA Platform Properties file:

```
cd /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin
open idea.properties
```

Now, Add the line:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Maximum file size (kilobytes) IDE should provide code assistance for.
# The larger file is the slower its editor works and higher overall system memory requirements are
# if code assistance is enabled. Remove this property or set to very large number if you need
# code assistance for any files available regardless their size.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500
```

Comment: use this `cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin`

The space between `Android` and `Studio` will not allow the terminal to locate the folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Help -> Edit Custom Properties...
2. Enter the following config:

   idea.max.intellisense.filesize=[VALUE IN KB]
3. Restart the Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

open this file: "/Android Studio/bin/idea.properties".
add this: idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500.
For reference only, it just works on windows.